# Multipane axis not aligning on highcharts

Tags: javascript, svg, charts, highcharts

Can someone help me with this?

I am trying to create a two pane stock chart using highcharts like the one here http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume/grid-light

In the bottom pane I have a spline which works fine. In the top pane I have stacked charts.

The problem is as soon as I add stack column series, the entire x-axis shrinks. 
It works fine if I have only 1 point on the stacked column. The problem happens when I add the second point onwards.

See attached html file please.

In the series, dataUpper & dataLower, if you keep only 1 point each, it works fine.

The code also shows some javascript error which I couldnt trace. Please help.

```js
var mainChart;

var dataUpper = [
{x:Date.UTC(2019,11,1), y:2732465.31},
{x:Date.UTC(2030,11,1), y:3985121.02},
{x:Date.UTC(2044,11,1), y:299609093.75}
];

var dataLower = [
{x:Date.UTC(2019,11,1), y:521848.29},
{x:Date.UTC(2030,11,1), y:186180.58},
{x:Date.UTC(2044,11,1), y:260108.95}
];


var dataValue = [{x:Date.UTC(2012,9,1), y:0.1},
{x:Date.UTC(2012,10,1), y:0.1},
{x:Date.UTC(2012,11,1), y:0.1},
{x:Date.UTC(2013,0,1), y:5518.56},
{x:Date.UTC(2013,1,1), y:10300.33},
{x:Date.UTC(2013,2,1), y:15671.37},
{x:Date.UTC(2013,3,1), y:21989.68},
{x:Date.UTC(2013,4,1), y:27647.17},
{x:Date.UTC(2013,5,1), y:32253.56},
{x:Date.UTC(2013,6,1), y:37007.76},
{x:Date.UTC(2013,7,1), y:40412.19},
{x:Date.UTC(2013,8,1), y:48018.32},
{x:Date.UTC(2013,9,1), y:58669.99},
{x:Date.UTC(2013,10,1), y:62818.42},
{x:Date.UTC(2013,11,1), y:69631.15},
{x:Date.UTC(2014,0,1), y:101940.34},
{x:Date.UTC(2014,1,1), y:142083.41},
{x:Date.UTC(2014,2,1), y:190098.12},
{x:Date.UTC(2014,3,1), y:225735.18},
{x:Date.UTC(2014,4,1), y:282481.53},
{x:Date.UTC(2014,5,1), y:335177.04},
{x:Date.UTC(2014,6,1), y:376437.44},
{x:Date.UTC(2014,7,1), y:424782.92},
{x:Date.UTC(2014,8,1), y:461288.14},
{x:Date.UTC(2014,9,1), y:519498.18},
{x:Date.UTC(2014,10,1), y:573153.55},
{x:Date.UTC(2014,11,1), y:587384.83},
{x:Date.UTC(2015,0,1), y:756685.47},
{x:Date.UTC(2015,1,1), y:884355.05},
{x:Date.UTC(2015,2,1), y:968137.83},
{x:Date.UTC(2015,3,1), y:1103011.2},
{x:Date.UTC(2015,4,1), y:1239214.91},
{x:Date.UTC(2015,5,1), y:1376762.08},
{x:Date.UTC(2015,6,1), y:1515665.95},
{x:Date.UTC(2015,7,1), y:1655939.92},
{x:Date.UTC(2015,8,1), y:1797597.48},
{x:Date.UTC(2015,9,1), y:1940652.3},
{x:Date.UTC(2015,10,1), y:2085118.15},
{x:Date.UTC(2015,11,1), y:2231008.95},
{x:Date.UTC(2016,0,1), y:2378338.76},
{x:Date.UTC(2016,1,1), y:2527121.77},
{x:Date.UTC(2016,2,1), y:2677372.31},
{x:Date.UTC(2016,3,1), y:2829104.85},
{x:Date.UTC(2016,4,1), y:2982334.03},
{x:Date.UTC(2016,5,1), y:3137074.59},
{x:Date.UTC(2016,6,1), y:3293341.45},
{x:Date.UTC(2016,7,1), y:3451149.66},
{x:Date.UTC(2016,8,1), y:3610514.42},
{x:Date.UTC(2016,9,1), y:3771451.09},
{x:Date.UTC(2016,10,1), y:3933975.17},
{x:Date.UTC(2016,11,1), y:4098102.32},
{x:Date.UTC(2017,0,1), y:4263848.36},
{x:Date.UTC(2017,1,1), y:4431229.24},
{x:Date.UTC(2017,2,1), y:4600261.1},
{x:Date.UTC(2017,3,1), y:4770960.21},
{x:Date.UTC(2017,4,1), y:4943343.03},
{x:Date.UTC(2017,5,1), y:5117426.16},
{x:Date.UTC(2017,6,1), y:5293226.38},
{x:Date.UTC(2017,7,1), y:5470760.62},
{x:Date.UTC(2017,8,1), y:5650045.97},
{x:Date.UTC(2017,9,1), y:5831099.73},
{x:Date.UTC(2017,10,1), y:6013939.32},
{x:Date.UTC(2017,11,1), y:6198582.37},
{x:Date.UTC(2018,0,1), y:6385046.65},
{x:Date.UTC(2018,1,1), y:6573350.14},
{x:Date.UTC(2018,2,1), y:6763510.98},
{x:Date.UTC(2018,3,1), y:6955547.49},
{x:Date.UTC(2018,4,1), y:7149478.16},
{x:Date.UTC(2018,5,1), y:7345321.69},
{x:Date.UTC(2018,6,1), y:7543096.93},
{x:Date.UTC(2018,7,1), y:7742822.94},
{x:Date.UTC(2018,8,1), y:7944518.97},
{x:Date.UTC(2018,9,1), y:8148204.45},
{x:Date.UTC(2018,10,1), y:8353898.99},
{x:Date.UTC(2018,11,1), y:8561622.41},
{x:Date.UTC(2019,0,1), y:8771394.73},
{x:Date.UTC(2019,1,1), y:8983236.16},
{x:Date.UTC(2019,2,1), y:9197167.11},
{x:Date.UTC(2019,3,1), y:9413208.18},
{x:Date.UTC(2019,4,1), y:9631380.18},
{x:Date.UTC(2019,5,1), y:9851704.15},
{x:Date.UTC(2019,6,1), y:10074201.3},
{x:Date.UTC(2019,7,1), y:10298893.06},
{x:Date.UTC(2019,8,1), y:10525801.09},
{x:Date.UTC(2019,9,1), y:10754947.25},
{x:Date.UTC(2019,10,1), y:10986353.61},
{x:Date.UTC(2019,11,1), y:11220042.47},
{x:Date.UTC(2020,0,1), y:8138822.7},
{x:Date.UTC(2020,1,1), y:8313623.87},
{x:Date.UTC(2020,2,1), y:8490149.2},
{x:Date.UTC(2020,3,1), y:8668415.7},
{x:Date.UTC(2020,4,1), y:8848440.55},
{x:Date.UTC(2020,5,1), y:9030241.08},
{x:Date.UTC(2020,6,1), y:9213834.83},
{x:Date.UTC(2020,7,1), y:9399239.46},
{x:Date.UTC(2020,8,1), y:9586472.85},
{x:Date.UTC(2020,9,1), y:9775553.02},
{x:Date.UTC(2020,10,1), y:9966498.21},
{x:Date.UTC(2020,11,1), y:10159326.8},
{x:Date.UTC(2021,0,1), y:10354057.37},
{x:Date.UTC(2021,1,1), y:10550708.68},
{x:Date.UTC(2021,2,1), y:10749299.67},
{x:Date.UTC(2021,3,1), y:10949849.49},
{x:Date.UTC(2021,4,1), y:11152377.44},
{x:Date.UTC(2021,5,1), y:11356903.05},
{x:Date.UTC(2021,6,1), y:11563446.01},
{x:Date.UTC(2021,7,1), y:11772026.22},
{x:Date.UTC(2021,8,1), y:11982663.78},
{x:Date.UTC(2021,9,1), y:12195378.98},
{x:Date.UTC(2021,10,1), y:12410192.31},
{x:Date.UTC(2021,11,1), y:12627124.48},
{x:Date.UTC(2022,0,1), y:12846196.37},
{x:Date.UTC(2022,1,1), y:13067429.09},
{x:Date.UTC(2022,2,1), y:13290843.96},
{x:Date.UTC(2022,3,1), y:13516462.5},
{x:Date.UTC(2022,4,1), y:13744306.45},
{x:Date.UTC(2022,5,1), y:13974397.75},
{x:Date.UTC(2022,6,1), y:14206758.58},
{x:Date.UTC(2022,7,1), y:14441411.32},
{x:Date.UTC(2022,8,1), y:14678378.58},
{x:Date.UTC(2022,9,1), y:14917683.18},
{x:Date.UTC(2022,10,1), y:15159348.18},
{x:Date.UTC(2022,11,1), y:15403396.86},
{x:Date.UTC(2023,0,1), y:15649852.74},
{x:Date.UTC(2023,1,1), y:15898739.55},
{x:Date.UTC(2023,2,1), y:16150081.28},
{x:Date.UTC(2023,3,1), y:16403902.14},
{x:Date.UTC(2023,4,1), y:16660226.58},
{x:Date.UTC(2023,5,1), y:16919079.3},
{x:Date.UTC(2023,6,1), y:17180485.23},
{x:Date.UTC(2023,7,1), y:17444469.56},
{x:Date.UTC(2023,8,1), y:17711057.73},
{x:Date.UTC(2023,9,1), y:17980275.4},
{x:Date.UTC(2023,10,1), y:18252148.53},
{x:Date.UTC(2023,11,1), y:18526703.3},
{x:Date.UTC(2024,0,1), y:18803966.16},
{x:Date.UTC(2024,1,1), y:19083963.82},
{x:Date.UTC(2024,2,1), y:19366723.27},
{x:Date.UTC(2024,3,1), y:19652271.74},
{x:Date.UTC(2024,4,1), y:19940636.73},
{x:Date.UTC(2024,5,1), y:20231846.04},
{x:Date.UTC(2024,6,1), y:20525927.71},
{x:Date.UTC(2024,7,1), y:20822910.09},
{x:Date.UTC(2024,8,1), y:21122821.77},
{x:Date.UTC(2024,9,1), y:21425691.65},
{x:Date.UTC(2024,10,1), y:21731548.92},
{x:Date.UTC(2024,11,1), y:22040423.04},
{x:Date.UTC(2025,0,1), y:22352343.76},
{x:Date.UTC(2025,1,1), y:22667341.13},
{x:Date.UTC(2025,2,1), y:22985445.51},
{x:Date.UTC(2025,3,1), y:23306687.53},
{x:Date.UTC(2025,4,1), y:23631098.15},
{x:Date.UTC(2025,5,1), y:23958708.62},
{x:Date.UTC(2025,6,1), y:24289550.51},
{x:Date.UTC(2025,7,1), y:24623655.68},
{x:Date.UTC(2025,8,1), y:24961056.32},
{x:Date.UTC(2025,9,1), y:25301784.94},
{x:Date.UTC(2025,10,1), y:25645874.36},
{x:Date.UTC(2025,11,1), y:25993357.74},
{x:Date.UTC(2026,0,1), y:26344268.55},
{x:Date.UTC(2026,1,1), y:26698640.6},
{x:Date.UTC(2026,2,1), y:27056508.02},
{x:Date.UTC(2026,3,1), y:27417905.3},
{x:Date.UTC(2026,4,1), y:27782867.25},
{x:Date.UTC(2026,5,1), y:28151429.03},
{x:Date.UTC(2026,6,1), y:28523626.15},
{x:Date.UTC(2026,7,1), y:28899494.46},
{x:Date.UTC(2026,8,1), y:29279070.18},
{x:Date.UTC(2026,9,1), y:29662389.88},
{x:Date.UTC(2026,10,1), y:30049490.49},
{x:Date.UTC(2026,11,1), y:30440409.29},
{x:Date.UTC(2027,0,1), y:30835183.95},
{x:Date.UTC(2027,1,1), y:31233852.5},
{x:Date.UTC(2027,2,1), y:31636453.35},
{x:Date.UTC(2027,3,1), y:32043025.29},
{x:Date.UTC(2027,4,1), y:32453607.48},
{x:Date.UTC(2027,5,1), y:32868239.48},
{x:Date.UTC(2027,6,1), y:33286961.24},
{x:Date.UTC(2027,7,1), y:33709813.1},
{x:Date.UTC(2027,8,1), y:34136835.78},
{x:Date.UTC(2027,9,1), y:34568070.44},
{x:Date.UTC(2027,10,1), y:35003558.62},
{x:Date.UTC(2027,11,1), y:35443342.27},
{x:Date.UTC(2028,0,1), y:35887463.77},
{x:Date.UTC(2028,1,1), y:36335965.89},
{x:Date.UTC(2028,2,1), y:36788891.85},
{x:Date.UTC(2028,3,1), y:37246285.28},
{x:Date.UTC(2028,4,1), y:37708190.24},
{x:Date.UTC(2028,5,1), y:38174651.24},
{x:Date.UTC(2028,6,1), y:38645713.22},
{x:Date.UTC(2028,7,1), y:39121421.56},
{x:Date.UTC(2028,8,1), y:39601822.08},
{x:Date.UTC(2028,9,1), y:40086961.08},
{x:Date.UTC(2028,10,1), y:40576885.28},
{x:Date.UTC(2028,11,1), y:41071641.89},
{x:Date.UTC(2029,0,1), y:41571278.57},
{x:Date.UTC(2029,1,1), y:42075843.45},
{x:Date.UTC(2029,2,1), y:42585385.15},
{x:Date.UTC(2029,3,1), y:43099952.76},
{x:Date.UTC(2029,4,1), y:43619595.85},
{x:Date.UTC(2029,5,1), y:44144364.48},
{x:Date.UTC(2029,6,1), y:44674309.2},
{x:Date.UTC(2029,7,1), y:45209481.08},
{x:Date.UTC(2029,8,1), y:45749931.67},
{x:Date.UTC(2029,9,1), y:46295713.04},
{x:Date.UTC(2029,10,1), y:46846877.76},
{x:Date.UTC(2029,11,1), y:47403478.95},
{x:Date.UTC(2030,0,1), y:47965570.21},
{x:Date.UTC(2030,1,1), y:48533205.71},
{x:Date.UTC(2030,2,1), y:49106440.12},
{x:Date.UTC(2030,3,1), y:49685328.68},
{x:Date.UTC(2030,4,1), y:50269927.16},
{x:Date.UTC(2030,5,1), y:50860291.86},
{x:Date.UTC(2030,6,1), y:51456479.68},
{x:Date.UTC(2030,7,1), y:52058548.04},
{x:Date.UTC(2030,8,1), y:52666554.96},
{x:Date.UTC(2030,9,1), y:53280559},
{x:Date.UTC(2030,10,1), y:53900619.31},
{x:Date.UTC(2030,11,1), y:54526795.64},
{x:Date.UTC(2031,0,1), y:50941249.49},
{x:Date.UTC(2031,1,1), y:51532782.57},
{x:Date.UTC(2031,2,1), y:52130150.29},
{x:Date.UTC(2031,3,1), y:52733410.2},
{x:Date.UTC(2031,4,1), y:53342620.41},
{x:Date.UTC(2031,5,1), y:53957839.61},
{x:Date.UTC(2031,6,1), y:54579127.07},
{x:Date.UTC(2031,7,1), y:55206542.66},
{x:Date.UTC(2031,8,1), y:55840146.81},
{x:Date.UTC(2031,9,1), y:56480000.56},
{x:Date.UTC(2031,10,1), y:57126165.56},
{x:Date.UTC(2031,11,1), y:57778704.07},
{x:Date.UTC(2032,0,1), y:58437678.94},
{x:Date.UTC(2032,1,1), y:59103153.66},
{x:Date.UTC(2032,2,1), y:59775192.34},
{x:Date.UTC(2032,3,1), y:60453859.73},
{x:Date.UTC(2032,4,1), y:61139221.22},
{x:Date.UTC(2032,5,1), y:61831342.82},
{x:Date.UTC(2032,6,1), y:62530291.22},
{x:Date.UTC(2032,7,1), y:63236133.75},
{x:Date.UTC(2032,8,1), y:63948938.42},
{x:Date.UTC(2032,9,1), y:64668773.89},
{x:Date.UTC(2032,10,1), y:65395709.52},
{x:Date.UTC(2032,11,1), y:66129815.33},
{x:Date.UTC(2033,0,1), y:66871162.06},
{x:Date.UTC(2033,1,1), y:67619821.12},
{x:Date.UTC(2033,2,1), y:68375864.64},
{x:Date.UTC(2033,3,1), y:69139365.46},
{x:Date.UTC(2033,4,1), y:69910397.13},
{x:Date.UTC(2033,5,1), y:70689033.93},
{x:Date.UTC(2033,6,1), y:71475350.88},
{x:Date.UTC(2033,7,1), y:72269423.73},
{x:Date.UTC(2033,8,1), y:73071328.98},
{x:Date.UTC(2033,9,1), y:73881143.89},
{x:Date.UTC(2033,10,1), y:74698946.47},
{x:Date.UTC(2033,11,1), y:75524815.51},
{x:Date.UTC(2034,0,1), y:76358830.58},
{x:Date.UTC(2034,1,1), y:77201072.02},
{x:Date.UTC(2034,2,1), y:78051620.98},
{x:Date.UTC(2034,3,1), y:78910559.4},
{x:Date.UTC(2034,4,1), y:79777970.03},
{x:Date.UTC(2034,5,1), y:80653936.43},
{x:Date.UTC(2034,6,1), y:81538543},
{x:Date.UTC(2034,7,1), y:82431874.95},
{x:Date.UTC(2034,8,1), y:83334018.36},
{x:Date.UTC(2034,9,1), y:84245060.13},
{x:Date.UTC(2034,10,1), y:85165088.04},
{x:Date.UTC(2034,11,1), y:86094190.71},
{x:Date.UTC(2035,0,1), y:87032457.66},
{x:Date.UTC(2035,1,1), y:87979979.29},
{x:Date.UTC(2035,2,1), y:88936846.87},
{x:Date.UTC(2035,3,1), y:89903152.59},
{x:Date.UTC(2035,4,1), y:90878989.54},
{x:Date.UTC(2035,5,1), y:91864451.75},
{x:Date.UTC(2035,6,1), y:92859634.13},
{x:Date.UTC(2035,7,1), y:93864632.58},
{x:Date.UTC(2035,8,1), y:94879543.91},
{x:Date.UTC(2035,9,1), y:95904465.91},
{x:Date.UTC(2035,10,1), y:96939497.3},
{x:Date.UTC(2035,11,1), y:97984737.81},
{x:Date.UTC(2036,0,1), y:99040288.13},
{x:Date.UTC(2036,1,1), y:100106249.96},
{x:Date.UTC(2036,2,1), y:101182725.99},
{x:Date.UTC(2036,3,1), y:102269819.92},
{x:Date.UTC(2036,4,1), y:103367636.5},
{x:Date.UTC(2036,5,1), y:104476281.47},
{x:Date.UTC(2036,6,1), y:105595861.66},
{x:Date.UTC(2036,7,1), y:106726484.92},
{x:Date.UTC(2036,8,1), y:107868260.16},
{x:Date.UTC(2036,9,1), y:109021297.41},
{x:Date.UTC(2036,10,1), y:110185707.72},
{x:Date.UTC(2036,11,1), y:111361603.29},
{x:Date.UTC(2037,0,1), y:112549097.41},
{x:Date.UTC(2037,1,1), y:113748304.46},
{x:Date.UTC(2037,2,1), y:114959339.99},
{x:Date.UTC(2037,3,1), y:116182320.67},
{x:Date.UTC(2037,4,1), y:117417364.32},
{x:Date.UTC(2037,5,1), y:118664589.92},
{x:Date.UTC(2037,6,1), y:119924117.63},
{x:Date.UTC(2037,7,1), y:121196068.79},
{x:Date.UTC(2037,8,1), y:122480565.94},
{x:Date.UTC(2037,9,1), y:123777732.84},
{x:Date.UTC(2037,10,1), y:125087694.45},
{x:Date.UTC(2037,11,1), y:126410576.97},
{x:Date.UTC(2038,0,1), y:127746507.84},
{x:Date.UTC(2038,1,1), y:129095615.78},
{x:Date.UTC(2038,2,1), y:130458030.75},
{x:Date.UTC(2038,3,1), y:131833884.02},
{x:Date.UTC(2038,4,1), y:133223308.12},
{x:Date.UTC(2038,5,1), y:134626436.92},
{x:Date.UTC(2038,6,1), y:136043405.59},
{x:Date.UTC(2038,7,1), y:137474350.65},
{x:Date.UTC(2038,8,1), y:138919409.95},
{x:Date.UTC(2038,9,1), y:140378722.71},
{x:Date.UTC(2038,10,1), y:141852429.51},
{x:Date.UTC(2038,11,1), y:143340672.35},
{x:Date.UTC(2039,0,1), y:144843594.58},
{x:Date.UTC(2039,1,1), y:146361341.01},
{x:Date.UTC(2039,2,1), y:147894057.86},
{x:Date.UTC(2039,3,1), y:149441892.78},
{x:Date.UTC(2039,4,1), y:151004994.89},
{x:Date.UTC(2039,5,1), y:152583514.79},
{x:Date.UTC(2039,6,1), y:154177604.55},
{x:Date.UTC(2039,7,1), y:155787417.74},
{x:Date.UTC(2039,8,1), y:157413109.45},
{x:Date.UTC(2039,9,1), y:159054836.3},
{x:Date.UTC(2039,10,1), y:160712756.46},
{x:Date.UTC(2039,11,1), y:162387029.65},
{x:Date.UTC(2040,0,1), y:164077817.16},
{x:Date.UTC(2040,1,1), y:165785281.9},
{x:Date.UTC(2040,2,1), y:167509588.35},
{x:Date.UTC(2040,3,1), y:169250902.64},
{x:Date.UTC(2040,4,1), y:171009392.52},
{x:Date.UTC(2040,5,1), y:172785227.4},
{x:Date.UTC(2040,6,1), y:174578578.38},
{x:Date.UTC(2040,7,1), y:176389618.22},
{x:Date.UTC(2040,8,1), y:178218521.39},
{x:Date.UTC(2040,9,1), y:180065464.1},
{x:Date.UTC(2040,10,1), y:181930624.28},
{x:Date.UTC(2040,11,1), y:183814181.62},
{x:Date.UTC(2041,0,1), y:185716317.57},
{x:Date.UTC(2041,1,1), y:187637215.4},
{x:Date.UTC(2041,2,1), y:189577060.15},
{x:Date.UTC(2041,3,1), y:191536038.72},
{x:Date.UTC(2041,4,1), y:193514339.84},
{x:Date.UTC(2041,5,1), y:195512154.09},
{x:Date.UTC(2041,6,1), y:197529673.94},
{x:Date.UTC(2041,7,1), y:199567093.75},
{x:Date.UTC(2041,8,1), y:201624609.83},
{x:Date.UTC(2041,9,1), y:203702420.37},
{x:Date.UTC(2041,10,1), y:205800725.57},
{x:Date.UTC(2041,11,1), y:207919727.58},
{x:Date.UTC(2042,0,1), y:210059630.53},
{x:Date.UTC(2042,1,1), y:212220640.58},
{x:Date.UTC(2042,2,1), y:214402965.93},
{x:Date.UTC(2042,3,1), y:216606816.83},
{x:Date.UTC(2042,4,1), y:218832405.58},
{x:Date.UTC(2042,5,1), y:221079946.61},
{x:Date.UTC(2042,6,1), y:223349656.44},
{x:Date.UTC(2042,7,1), y:225641753.73},
{x:Date.UTC(2042,8,1), y:227956459.31},
{x:Date.UTC(2042,9,1), y:230293996.18},
{x:Date.UTC(2042,10,1), y:232654589.53},
{x:Date.UTC(2042,11,1), y:235038466.78},
{x:Date.UTC(2043,0,1), y:237445857.6},
{x:Date.UTC(2043,1,1), y:239876993.91},
{x:Date.UTC(2043,2,1), y:242332109.93},
{x:Date.UTC(2043,3,1), y:244811442.19},
{x:Date.UTC(2043,4,1), y:247315229.54},
{x:Date.UTC(2043,5,1), y:249843713.19},
{x:Date.UTC(2043,6,1), y:252397136.75},
{x:Date.UTC(2043,7,1), y:254975746.21},
{x:Date.UTC(2043,8,1), y:257579789.99},
{x:Date.UTC(2043,9,1), y:260209518.96},
{x:Date.UTC(2043,10,1), y:262865186.48},
{x:Date.UTC(2043,11,1), y:265547048.39},
{x:Date.UTC(2044,0,1), y:268255363.06},
{x:Date.UTC(2044,1,1), y:270990391.41},
{x:Date.UTC(2044,2,1), y:273752396.94},
{x:Date.UTC(2044,3,1), y:276541645.72},
{x:Date.UTC(2044,4,1), y:279358406.49},
{x:Date.UTC(2044,5,1), y:282202950.6},
{x:Date.UTC(2044,6,1), y:285075552.11},
{x:Date.UTC(2044,7,1), y:287976487.75},
{x:Date.UTC(2044,8,1), y:290906037},
{x:Date.UTC(2044,9,1), y:293864482.09},
{x:Date.UTC(2044,10,1), y:296852108.05},
{x:Date.UTC(2044,11,1), y:299869202.7},
{x:Date.UTC(2045,0,1), y:0.1},
{x:Date.UTC(2045,1,1), y:0.1},
{x:Date.UTC(2045,2,1), y:0.1}];

$(function () {

    mainChart = new Highcharts.StockChart({

        chart: {
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            height:474,
     style: {
    fontFamily: "Dosis, sans-serif"
     },
     marginLeft:30,
            renderTo : 'container'
        },
        title: {
            text: ' '
        },
        xAxis: {
         type:'datetime',
         gridLineWidth: 0,
            lineWidth:1,
        },
        yAxis: [{
         type: 'logarithmic',
         pointStart: 1,
            min: 10000,
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            lineWidth:0,
            title: {
                text: 'Check',
                align:'left'
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: false,
            },
            height: '60%'
        },
        {
            title: {
                text: 'Value',
                align:'left'
            },
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            lineWidth:0,
            top:'63%',
            height: '36%'
        }],
        legend: {
         enabled: false,
        },
  plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
        series: [
   {
          type: 'areaspline',
             name: 'Value',
    yAxis: 1,
    dataGrouping: {
     enabled: false
    },
             data: dataValue,
             color:'rgba(145, 235, 134, 0.6)',
             lineWidth:1,
             lineColor:'rgba(145, 235, 134, 1)',
    fillColor : {
                    linearGradient : {
                        x1: 0,
                        y1: 0,
                        x2: 0,
                        y2: 1
                    },
                    stops : [
                        [0, 'rgba(145, 235, 134, 0.6)'],
                        [0.9, 'rgba(145, 235, 134, 0.1)']
                    ]
                },
             dataLabels:{
              enabled:false
             },
             tooltip: {
     enabled:true,
     useHTML: true,
     formatter: function () {
      return '<div class="growthtip">1 Cr</div>';
     }
          }
         },
         {
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Upper',
    dataGrouping: {
     enabled: false
    },
    data: dataUpper,
    stack:'stackFlag',
    //pointWidth: 6,
    dataLabels: {
     enabled:true,
     useHTML: true,
     verticalAlign: 'top',
     x:0,
     y:-33,
     style:{
      fontWeight:'normal',
      textShadow: 'none'
     }
    }

         },
   {
          type: 'column',
             name: 'Lower',
    dataGrouping: {
     enabled: false
    },
             data: dataLower,
    stack:'stackFlag',
             dataLabels:{
              enabled:true,
              useHTML: true,
              verticalAlign: 'top',
              style:{
               fontWeight:'normal',
               textShadow: 'none'
               }
             }
         }
        ]
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div id="container" style="height: 510px">
</div>
```

Regards,
SS

Comment: Do you have any working fiddle?

Comment: see this... http://jsfiddle.net/05th6144/1/   delete the first and second datapoints in dataUpper & dataLower series and see that the chart is forming properly on full width. However with more than 1 datapoints, it contracts and doesn't plot on full x-axis. Besides, when you play with the navigator you see some issues with the charts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable align:left on both yAxis (which causes errors with navigator). Next step is set disable ordinal xAxis and set pointRange on column serie.

```
    xAxis: {
        ordinal:false,
        type:'datetime',
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        lineWidth:1,
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            pointRange: 365 * 30 * 24 * 3600
        }
    },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/05th6144/2/